# Variance Problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm brushing up on some basic stats, but I'm having trouble with this problem. 
Let $A,B\subseteq [n]$ be chosen uniformity at random. Compute the variance of $|A\cup B|$

I know $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2=E((X-\overline{X})^2)$

But I'm not very comfortable with random variables and don't know how to calculate the expected value of a squared variable

Comment: You can find $E(X^2)$ the same way as the expectation of any variable; for a discrete distribution, take $y\,P(X^2=y)$, summed over all values of $y$ that $X^2$ can take. On the other hand, I think $|A\cup B|$ has a binomial distribution here; if so, there's already a known formula for its variance.

Comment: What does $[n]$ represent here? Is that an interval, or a finite set of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1,\dots,n$, let $X_i = 1$ if $i \in A \cup B$ and $0$ otherwise. Then you are required to find $\operatorname{Var}(\sum X_i)$.

Since $X_i$ is independent of (hence uncorrelated with) $X_j$ for $i \ne j$, this in turn is $\sum \operatorname{Var}(X_i) = n \operatorname{Var}(X_1)$.

We have 
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_1) = E(X_1^2) - E(X_1)^2 = E(X_1) - E(X_1)^2 = (3/4) - (3/4)^2 = 3/16,$$
so the answer is $\frac{3}{16}n$.